# How do I implement a SVM for a monotonic (non-decreasing) function in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, svm

I have a simple regression equation which goes someting like

```
svm_cv<-tune( svm,
              count~day_index, 
              kernel="radial", 
              scale=TRUE,
              data=bdata,
              ranges=list(cost=2^(-8:8),
                          gamma=2^(-8:8))
)
```

Now the value for `count` can never decrease as the `day_index` increases which I can see is not true when I plot the predictions made from model `svm_cv$best.model`

How do I apply this restriction in R?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same requirement: I have been pointed to the **isoreg** library by reddit user *puzzler10* which seems to have done what I needed

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/isoreg.html

Comment: This is not an SVM though? Nevertheless, you can also do a search on https://rseek.org/ on __isotonic__ and select packages. This yields 18 packages for me most of which might be interesting.